# Laravel createMany error on nested relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-relations

This is in relation to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72286191/laravel-createmany-on-createmany-while-preserving-relation). I'm having this error:

```
TypeError
Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, int given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 920
```

While inserting data using createMany. This is the form request data:

```
{
  "name": "My Order",
  "orders": [
    {
      "date": "2022-05-17",
      "product_id": [1],
      "price": 1
    },
    {
      "start_date": "2022-05-18",
      "product_id": [2],
      "price": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the **store** method:

```
$order = auth()->user()->orders()->create($request->validated());
$order_subs = $order->subOrders()->createMany($request->orders);
$order_sub_items = $request->only('orders')['orders'];

foreach ($order_subs as $key => $value) {
    $value->subOrderProducts()->createMany([$order_sub_items[$key]);
}
```

However, if the product_id is not an array, it will store properly. Sample form request data:

```
{
  "name": "My Order",
  "orders": [
    {
      "date": "2022-05-17",
      "product_id": 1,
      "price": 1
    },
    {
      "start_date": "2022-05-18",
      "product_id": 2,
      "price": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Obviously you fix the error by passing an array, not an int, to whatever is causing the error. There's a traceback that will tell you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: @miken32 hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. Believe me or not, the error is quite the opposite and is misleading. As you can see, I have provided an array for the product_id, but the error is the opposite. I'm also having a hard time figuring out how to do a createMany for nested relations. Haven't seen any resources for reference.